# Trigger para update before insert

Tags: mysql, trigger

Meu banco de dados possui duas tabelas, a notificacao e a atendimento, conforme mostra a imagem.

[image: Tabelas do BD]

Na tabela notificação o valor padrão do status é  "em aberto".

Eu tentei fazer uma trigger que atualize o status padrão "em aberto" para "em atendimento" depois que seja inserido um novo atendimento na tabela atendimento
Minha trigger acabou alterando o status de todos os registros na tabela notificação, e eu quero que seja alterado apenas o status da notificação que seja referenciada na tabela atendimento.

Segue abaixo o código da minha trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER atualizanotificacao BEFORE INSERT ON atendimento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE notificacao SET status = "Em atendimento" WHERE idnotificacao = idnotificacao;

END
// DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele esta alterando todos os registros porque idnotificacao = idnotificao é o mesmo que 1 = 1. em todas as linhas essa condição iria retornar verdadeiro.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER atualizanotificacao BEFORE INSERT ON atendimento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE notificacao SET status = "Em atendimento" WHERE idnotificacao = NEW.idnotificacao;

END
// DELIMITER ;
```

Este *NEW* que adicionei significa que vou pegar o valor de idnotificacao que será inserido na tabela atendimento, o idnotificacao sem o *NEW* é da tabela notificacao mesmo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo!! Muito Obrigado :)